# socket error - python

Tags: python, sockets

i want to get the local private machine's address, running the following piece of code:

```
socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())
```

gives the error:

```
socket.herror: [Errno 2] Host name lookup failure
```

i know i can see local machine's address, by using

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

but it shows the public address of my network (or machine) and ifcofig shows another address for my wlan. can some one help me on this issue? Thanks

Comment: did you import socket??

Comment: @ruddra if she didn't, that would result in a totally different error (`NameError`), that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: yes i did import socket and installed nscd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're going to find [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces/0.10.4) a little more useful here.

It appears to be a cross-platform library to deal with Network Interfaces.

**Example:**

```
>>> from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses
>>> interfaces()
['lo', 'sit0', 'enp3s0', 'docker0']
>>> ifaddresses("enp3s0")
{17: [{'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'addr': 'bc:5f:f4:97:5a:69'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '10.0.0.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '10.0.0.2'}], 10: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': '2001:470:edee:0:be5f:f4ff:fe97:5a69'}, {'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe97:5a69%enp3s0'}]}
>>> 
>>> ifaddresses("enp3s0")[2][0]["addr"]
'10.0.0.2'  # <-- My Desktop's LAN IP Address.
```

Comment: tnx that worked fine and was what i wanted, but is there a way to find the IP address using sockets?

Comment: No not really. Not in the way you describe. The ``sockets`` modules only provides the two functions you've already seen and they're limited at best.